# Ruby on Rails Activerecord Named Scope Criteria on Nested Model Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following tables (showing only the primary and foreign keys along with the name in the udds table):

```
employee    appointment    appointment_udds    udds
--------    -----------    ----------------    ----
id          id             id                  id
            employee_id    appointment_id      name
                           udds_id
```

I setup the relationships in models as follows:

**employee.rb**

```
has_many :appointments, :dependent => :destroy
```

**appointment.rb**

```
has_many :appointment_uddss, :dependent => destroy
belongs_to :employee
```

**appointment_udds.rb**

```
belongs_to :appointment
belongs_to :udds
```

**udds.rb**

```
has_many :appointment_uddss
```

---

So I'm working primarily with the Employee model and I was trying to create a named scope in it's model to get all records which have a non-null udds name, like so:

**employee.rb**

```
named_scope :with_udds, :include => :uddss, :conditions => "udds.name IS NOT NULL"
```

I was hoping to call **Employee.with_udds** to get all the employees that have a non-null name field for their udds. Is this relationship too complex for ActiveRecord or am I going about this the wrong way?

---

I tried expanding out the relationship down to the udds table in the employee class as well:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_audited
  has_many :appointments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :appointment_uddss, :through => :appointments
  has_many :uddss, :through => :appointment_uddss

  named_scope :with_udds, :include => :uddss, :conditions => "udds.name IS NOT NULL"
```

Then in the console:

> Employee.with_udds

returns an empty set (there is data where udds.name != null in the db)

Answer (score 0):

Lay out the includes explicitly:

```
:include => { :appointments => { :appointment_uddss => :uddss } }
```

Comment: passing a parameters hash is deprecated in Rails 3.1

Comment: @Caley `named_scope` was deprecated in Rails 3.0, so I assume the question applies to 2.x

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_audited
  has_many :appointments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :appointment_uddss, :through => :appointments
  has_many :uddss, :through => :appointment_uddss

  scope :with_udds, where("udds.name IS NOT NULL").includes(:udds)
end
```